# How do I add a fade to an append?

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, fadein

I haven't been able to adapt the examples I have found in stackoverflow that describe how to add a fade to an append, and I can't work out why.

I have the following code for using ajax to replace a contact form with a success message:

```
$.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "contact-engine.php",
         data: dataString,
         success: function() {
           $('#contact-form').html("<div id='message-form'></div>");
           $('#message-form').html("<h3>Your message has been submitted successfully!</h3>")
           .hide()
           .fadeIn(2000, function() {
             $('#message-form').append('<p style="text-align:center">Thanks for getting in touch. I will get back to you as soon as possible.</p>');
           });
         }
       });
       return false;
```

I am trying to get the append to fade in.  I tried adding .hide().fadeIn(2000) after the append html, but this didn't work. Could someone help me out with this?

Thanks,

Nick

Comment: I don't have an exact solution, but you're appending as a callback. That means it doesn't append until after it fades. Try something like hide().append('Your <p> tag').fadeIn(2000); -- edit: What I would do, without testing code, is something like instead of hide/fadein/append, I would do .animate({opacity: 0},0).append('<p>Some p content</p>').animate({opacity: 1},2000); -- that's just a safe way I am confident would work without me testing code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add `hide` and `fadeIn` after `append`, the problem is that you will be hiding and fading the container, not the element you are adding.  If you change it to `appendTo` it should work:

```
$(NEW_ELEMENT).appendTo(SOMETHING).hide().fadeIn(2000)
```

An example:  http://jsfiddle.net/U4d9G/

Comment: Thanks James, that sorted it.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to hide before the append....
Something like this:

> $(NEW_ELEMENT).hide().appendTo(SOMETHING).fadeIn();

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("<h3>Records has been successfully modified.</h3>").appendTo("#body").fadeIn(2000).fadeOut(4000);
    //$("#body").html("<div id='message-form'></div>");

});
</script>

<style type="text/css">
h3{
    text-align:center;
    width:30%;
    padding:15px 0;
    top:100px;
    position:absolute;
    color:snow;
    left:35%;
    background:darkred;

    /*
     darkgreen, snow
    darkred, snow

     */
}
</style>
```